# Capture text groups in paragraph Regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture header and their corresponding value from the paragraph.

Example,

**Paragraph** : "INTRODUCTION: There was a beautiful village. CONCLUSION: End of the story"

**Regex used**: \b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\b(?:[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):|$)

**Output**: [('INTRODUCTION', 'There was a beautiful village'), ('CONCLUSION': 'End of the story')]

There is no problem in this. But sometime I get patterns like,

**Paragraph**: "There was a beautiful garden once. INTRODUCTION: There was a beautiful village. CONCLUSION: End of the story"

**Output Expected**: [('FreeText', 'There was a beautiful garden once'), ('INTRODUCTION', 'There was a beautiful village'), ('CONCLUSION': 'End of the story')]

How to achieve the above case in case some free text are coming up. Any help is appreciated.....

Comment: Do you really need regex here? Can't just split the string on `Intro` or `Conclusion`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to use a look behind assertion in most cases because the case will be of unknown length.

You could try matching for the beginning of the text (if the paragraph you've shown us is typically how the string looks).

This will match the cases *without* free text:

```
^\b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)):\s(.?)(?=\s\b(?:[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):|$)
```

If you have cases that are in the form:

```
^\b([A-Z][a-z]+[.])
```

Then you know you have a case that starts with free text because of the absence of an all capitalized key word. So you could add something like this to the start of your regex and just have two different cases for matching.